# How to break for loop from function?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have an update function which call a process function. Sometimes I need to break the for loop, but to do that I need to communicate from the process function to the loop running in update().
I'm passing a false to detect the break intention in process().

Is this a good way of interrupting the for loop in update()?

```
var system = {

  update: function() {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
      var r = this.process(i);
      if (r == false) break;
    }

  },
  process: function(i) {
    console.log('test ' + i);
    if (i == 4) return false;
  }
}

system.update();
```

Comment: Yep, I'd do the same.

Comment: You'll want to return `true` when you don't want to break. If you don't return anything, you have a weird result where `undefined` means keep going and `false` means stop.

Comment: Sure that'll work. That's what return values are for, to communicate some data. You can eliminate the variable though `if (this.process(i) == false) break;`.